# Azure custom Policy that allows only Azure Functions creation on ASE

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-policy

I have an Azure ASE v3 environment to be used for compute needs of Azure Functions.

I want to ensure **only** Azure Functions can be deployed onto this ASE environment.

Logic Apps or Web Apps should *NOT* be allowed to be even created.

`"Microsoft.Web/sites"` seems to be a catch all for all of Logic Apps, Web Apps and Functions.

How to achieve ensure separated identification of just Azure Functions to achieve this objective ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kind` to filter Function Apps.

```json
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "kind": "functionapp", // windows
    "kind": "functionapp,linux", // linux
```

Could be something like this:

```
"if": {
    "allOf": [
        {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
        },
        {
            "field": "kind",
            "equals": "functionapp"
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: hmm - does not work- still allows Logic APps to be created. is the Then clause to deny right?

Comment: You can change the kind to the value for logic apps if you use deny, or negate the check to deny if kind is not function app.